# Appium GUI runs older version of Appium than console

Tags: appium

when I run appium through the terminal with the command "Appium &" it runs appium 1.4.10

When I run it from my GUI (which I need to do to use the inspector) it runs 1.4.8

Any ideas how I can make it run with the latest version from the GUI?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Itseems you have installed appium ver 1.4.10 at a system level, but the gui you installed is of version 1.4.8. So you should probably download the corresponding gui version - 1.4.10 dmg or exe and install the GUI